# Qt QIcon SVG different sizes

Tags: c++, qt

I am using the QIcon class of Qt to set the application icon of my apps.

My icons are SVG files, which load just fine.

```
QIcon appIcon;
QString iconPath = "share/icons/myapp.svg;
QFile iconFile(iconPath);
if (iconFile.exists()) {
    appIcon.addFile(iconPath);
}

QApplication::setWindowIcon(appIcon);
```

My question is:
I want to have different icons for different pusposes.
For instance, I'd like to have different icons (i.e. sizes) for the title bar and for the actual icon, showed when pressing `ALT+TAB`.

I found the `QSize` parameter of `addFile()`, but then, the icon would stick to one certain size, which I don't know (because different window managers could have different title bar sizes).

How can I define an icon for the title bar and one for the rest (that's pretty much the short version of what I am asking)?

Kind regards,
mefiX

Answer (score 2):

I normally use a separate PNG image (16x16 pixels, e.g. "./Icons/app_window.png") to set the title bar icon using the setWindowIcon() function in my mainwindow class constructor:

```
this->setWindowIcon(QIcon(QLatin1String(":/Images/Icons/app_window.png")));
```

For the rest icons you can use the following excellent freeware application:
http://www.icofx.ro/

It allows you to create both a "myapp.ico" file (for MS-Windows) and a "myapp.icns" file (for Mac OSX) and if you start from a 256x256 image it can automatically create all icon sizes for you!

**For Mac OS/X** you must put the following line in your "MyApp.pro" file:

```
ICON = Icons/myapp.icns
```

**For MS-Windows** you must put the following line in your "MyApp.pro" file:

```
win32::RC_FILE = myapp.rc
```

and you have also to create a "myapp.rc" file that look like this:

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON    DISCARDABLE     "./Icons/myapp.ico"

#include <windows.h>
#include "MyAppVersion.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",    VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",        VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",       VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",        VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

The #include "MyAppVersion.h" and the rest options is off-course optional but you can use it to define all the VER_xxx constants instead of putting them directly as a constant string like "MyAppName". The only important line for icon definition is the first one:

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON    DISCARDABLE     "./Icons/myapp.ico"
```

which implies that a file "MyApp.ico" resides in the folder ./Icons/

Note also that on MS-Windows if you modify your "myapp.ico" file, rebuild your project and run your application again, the icon is not always displayed right, due to the icon cache of windows-explorer.
Here is a link with various methods to clear/rebuild the windows-explorer icon cache:
[Rebuild icon cache to fix incorrectly displayed icons](http://smallvoid.com/article/windows-icon-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one SVG-Icon in different position, it should be scaled when drawn. But the application icon (shown at ALT+TAB) is different, see the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/appicon.html).

To learn how to convert SVG icons to the ico format, look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/162458/how-to-convert-svg-to-windows-ico-or-mac-icns-icons).

Comment: The funny thing is that the icon shown in [ALT+TAB] is the one I set via `QApplication::setWindowIcon()`. According to your statement, I would expect that this does not work ...

Comment: I was assuming you are using MS-Windows (you did not tell us). And according to the Qt documentation (and the answer of Fivos) you need an icon in the RC file, so that the windows explorer can show an application icon. But maybe [ALT+TAB] uses a different method to locate the icon.